# delete button with confirmation in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, crud

This view.php is generated with CRUD in Yii2 but the delete button doesn't confirm window.

But in index.php generated with CRUD in Yii2, The confirm window for delete worked.

```
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Back','index', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
</p>
```

Delete Button in index.php:

```
<a href="var/delete?id=2" title="Delete" aria-label="Delete" data-pjax="0" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this item?" data-method="post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Delete Button in view.php:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="var/delete?id=2" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this item?" data-method="post">Delete</a>
```

Comment: so you mean index.php delete is showing confirmation, but this one not? if yes then check the actual html of both button and you will found some difference. overcome that difference and this one will work also

Comment: i add code Diff , but dont work.

Comment: i think for JS file , in view.php any include js files from yii.

Comment: Do you have some Javascript errors? Because then it's clear that the js confirm doesn't work. Please check your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [section about yii.js](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#yii.js) is still in progress.

To get default support of confirmation you should register [yii.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.js).

Using [yii\web\YiiAsset](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#common-asset-bundles)

```
use yii\web\YiiAsset;
YiiAsset::register($this);
```

or [registering script files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#script-files) (not recommend, just for example)

```
$this->registerJsFile('@yii/assets/yii.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```